# AWS EC2 CLI run-instance attaching an Iam Instance Profile

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface

I need my Iam Role to be available during execution of the userdata script, so I need to add it as part of the run-instance process.
I have a profile already:

```
{
    "CreateDate": "2017-08-30T16:37:04Z",
    "InstanceProfileId": "AIPAJIHTVB7JBMRURGGWU",
    "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::306196228564:instance-profile/ec2_describe_tags",
    "Path": "/",
    "InstanceProfileName": "ec2_describe_tags",
    "Roles": [
        {
            "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
                "Version": "2012-10-17",
                "Statement": [
                    {
                        "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
                        "Effect": "Allow",
                        "Principal": {
                            "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            "CreateDate": "2017-08-30T16:37:04Z",
            "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::306196228564:role/ec2_describe_tags",
            "Path": "/",
            "RoleName": "ec2_describe_tags",
            "RoleId": "AROAIHYX34TXI3VIEPCBE"
        }
    ]
}
```

I start my instances with a json file, and the json skeleton states that I can add an instance profile with:

```
"IamInstanceProfile": {
    "Arn": "",
    "Name": ""
},
```

Unfortunately, the skeleton and the documentaton never says what goes in "Name".
I tried with just the Arn, I tried with the InstanceProfileName in the Name field, I tried with the ID in the Name Field, etc.

My instances create without error, butdescribe-iam-instance-profile-associations does not show that my instance is associated with a profile and, of course.  I don't have the access I need (ec2:describeTags).

What might I be doing wrong?

Comment: Are you referring to the `IamInstanceProfile` field within a `AWS::EC2::Instance` CloudFormation entry? The [AWS::EC2::Instance](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-instance.html#cfn-ec2-instance-iaminstanceprofile) documentation only shows this as a string, not an object with `Arn` and `Name` entries. Where did you get this skeleton?

Comment: I was referring to the command line 'aws cli run-instance...'   The problem is resolved though.  I'm embarrassed to say it was operator error.  The process I described above works, when I don't mess it up.